# Find command in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find

What does the following means ?

```
find myDirectory -name myFile -exec ls \-ln {} \;
```

I've looked [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ufind.htm) but didn't understand exactly

```
-exec command   True if the executed command returns a zero value as exit status. The end of command must be punctuated by an escaped semicolon. A command argument {} is replaced by the current path name.
```

This part `-exec ls \-ln {} \;` is not clear to me .

Regards

Comment: Off-topic.  But try a proper man page: e.g. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find.  Or even Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)#Execute_an_action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means: find all files with a name `myFile` in the current directory and all its subdirectories and for every file that was found run `ls -ln` with the name of the file.

For example:

```
$ mkdir a
$ touch myFile a/myFile
$ find -name myFile -exec ls -ln {} \;
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Jun 17 13:07 ./myFile
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Jun 17 13:07 ./a/myFile
```

In this case `find` will run `ls` twice:

```
ls -ln ./myFile
ls -ln ./a/myFile
```

Every time it will expand `{}` as the fullname of the found file.

Also I must add that you need the backslash before -ln in this case. Yes, you can use it, but it is absolutely useless here.

Answer (score 3):

```
find myDirectory -name myFile -exec ls \-ln {} \;
```

It says find `myFile` in directory `myDirectory` and once all the files are found then execute the file listing command, that is in linix `ls` with command options  `-l` and `-n` on the files found.

So, ultimately you will get all the `myFiles` accompanied with `ls` command result.

Comment: exec executes the command on every found file, not on the group

Comment: @fvu, that just an explanation ... I mean the same thing.

Comment: just pointing out that the explanation could lead to misunderstandings - your edit makes it a lot clearer, +1